# Unable to Properly Code Stacked Bar Chart With "Yes/No" Categories

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

I am very new to R and this may seem like an easy fix but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to do this. So the question in this survey is along the lines of "Do you use this site?" and respondents are asked to answer "yes" or "no".

Here's my data frame:

```
ic <- data.frame(items = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                                    "item6", "item7","item8", "item9", "item10", 
                                    "item11", "item12"),
                        yes = c("6", "6", "7", "4", "2", "6", "6", "8", "2", 
                                "3", "7", "6"), 
                        no = c("2", "2", "1", "4", "6", "2", "2", "0", "6", "5",
                               "1", "2"))
```

And this is what it looks like when I use the head(ic) function:

```
head(ic)
```

```
 items yes no
1 item1   6  2
2 item2   6  2
3 item3   7  1
4 item4   4  4
5 item5   2  6
6 item6   6  2
```

I use this code to plot it:

```
ic %>%
  gather(key = "success", value=value, -items) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=items, y=value, fill=success)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "Items People Use", x= "Items", y= "# of individuals")+
  scale_fill_brewer("legend", palette = "Spectral")
```

[stacked chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWD3n.png)
but then it ends up looking like this, which is visually very confusing and not *quite* what I'm looking for because
a) the yes and no columns aren't uniform if that makes sense
b) it also goes past the number of respondents (there are 8 in total)
c) the items are not in numerical order, should be item 1, 2, 3, etc...

Any help on this would be very much appreciated, as I think it might possibly because of my dataframe being in the wrong structure but I have no idea how to go about fixing this!!

Answer (score 1):

I would do that:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ic <- data.frame(items = c("item01", "item02", "item03", "item04", "item05", 
                           "item06", "item07","item08", "item09", "item10", 
                           "item11", "item12"),
                 yes = c("6", "6", "7", "4", "2", "6", "6", "8", "2", 
                         "3", "7", "6"), 
                 no = c("2", "2", "1", "4", "6", "2", "2", "0", "6", "5",
                        "1", "2"))

df <- ic %>%
  gather(key = "success", value=val, -items)
df$success <- factor(df$success, levels = c('yes', 'no'))
df$val <- as.numeric(df$val)
df <- df[order(df$items),]


ggplot(df, aes(x=items, y=val)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = success),position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
coord_flip()+
labs(title = "Items People Use", x= "Items", y= "# of individuals")+
scale_fill_brewer("legend", palette = "Spectral")
```

[image: stack bar]

I technically didn't solve your problem of items sorting, but I always pad my numbers with relevant number of 0 so that I never have to waste my life with this kind of issues.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using all the suggestions from all the answers provided :)

Answer (score 1):

a and b are happening because you set up your yes and no as characters. If you declare them to be numeric, it will order the "yes" and "no" correctly and stop at the beginning and end numbers.
For c, to order, you can assign to be a factor and order the levels how you wish. In this case, as the levels are in ascending order, you can add forcats::fct_inorder and the factors will be in the order they are first encountered. Without coord_flip, you would see the items in ascending order. However, when you flip it will rotate counterclockwise. You can reverse that order with forcats::fct_rev. So, you can revise your data as:

```
  ic <- data.frame(items = forcats::fct_rev(forcats::fct_inorder(c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                           "item6", "item7","item8", "item9", "item10", 
                           "item11", "item12"))),
                 yes = as.numeric(c("6", "6", "7", "4", "2", "6", "6", "8", "2", 
                         "3", "7", "6")), 
                 no = as.numeric(c("2", "2", "1", "4", "6", "2", "2", "0", "6", "5",
                        "1", "2")))
```

and this will plot as you desire

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I ended up combining all 3 answers on the page to get the desired result :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix your data frame, you could

1. define items as a factor with specified levels
2. change the type of yes and no responses to numeric

```
library(tidyverse)

ic %>% 
  mutate(
    # change items to factor variable, and specify levels
    items = factor(items, 
                   levels = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                              "item6", "item7","item8", "item9", "item10", 
                              "item11", "item12")),
    # change the type of your responses to numeric
    yes = as.numeric(yes),
    no = as.numeric(no)
  )
```

Or you can apply it directly to your graph:

```
ic %>% 
  mutate(
    items = factor(items, 
                   levels = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                              "item6", "item7","item8", "item9", "item10", 
                              "item11", "item12")),
    yes = as.numeric(yes),
    no = as.numeric(no)
  ) %>%
  gather(key = "success", value=value, -items) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=items, y=value, fill=success)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "Items People Use", x = "Items", y= "# of individuals")+
  scale_fill_brewer("legend", palette = "Spectral")
```

The result looks like this:

[Final bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCJ0P.png)

Comment: Hi thank you! I ended combining this answer with the 2 others who kindly replied to get the desired outcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you again everyone who replied. This the code I ended up going for:

```
ic <- data.frame(items = forcats::fct_rev(forcats::fct_inorder(c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                                                                 "item6", "item7","item8", "item9", "item10", 
                                                                 "item11", "item12"))),
                 yes = c("6", "6", "7", "4", "2", "6", "6", "8", "2", 
                                    "3", "7", "6"), 
                 no = c("2", "2", "1", "4", "6", "2", "2", "0", "6", "5",
                                   "1", "2"))

ic %>% 
  mutate(
    yes = as.numeric(yes),
    no = as.numeric(no)
  ) %>%
  gather(key = "success", value=value, -items) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=items, y=value, fill=success)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "Items People Use", x = "Items", y= "# of individuals")+
  scale_fill_brewer("legend", palette = "Spectral")
```

Which gave me the desired chart here! Thank you again everyone.

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpFJu.png)